# How to fetch all children element input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dynamic

I am stuck at one point where I have to fetch all the input element where the action is perform.

eg : 
there is a container in which can have n number of input element like 
input type text/ number/ date 
radio button
etc (rendered dynamically)

and there is button called submit in the same container. 
when I click on submit

1. I have to get parent of submit button element
2. fetch all the element inside this parent container

How can I do this ?

since I am rendering dynamically I couldn't set scope so that I can access with scope.

Comment: Questions: 
1. Are you using JQuery?
2. Can we please see some code for our reference?

Comment: Sounds quite simple. But post your HTML and JS
.

Comment: u should set ng-form="myparent"  , then set your input fields like ng-model="myparent.firstname" and etc  ...

Comment: can you show your code for more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use jquery you can do it as followed:

```
var $parent = $(button).parent();
var $inputs = $parent.find("input");
```

if you aren't using jquery you can use the following:

```
var parent = buttonElement.parentElement;
var inputs = parent.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works partially but I got to know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" value="Aslam"/>
    <input type="radio" value="Select" />

    <input type="button"  id="btnClick" value="Click Me!"/>

</div>
<script>
    $("#btnClick").on('click', function () {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var childrens = parent.children("input");

        childrens.each(function () {
            switch (this.type) {
                case 'text':
                    alert('Put text box logic');
                    break;
                case 'radio':
                    alert('Put radio box logic');
                    break;
                    //Put other control
                default:
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First set ng-form and access through ng-model ... This is the simple way of doing this ...

```
<form ng-form="myparent">

    <input type="text" ng-model="myparent.firstname"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myparent.lastname"/>
    ... Etc

    </form>
```